# In what occasion can onNext() be called more than once?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I have defined and interface, with an endpoint that returns JSON. Retrofit converts this JSON into MyObject. It could be also a list, map, etc, it doesn't matter now.

This is how I subscribe.

```
    subscription = Retrofit.create(MyApi.class)
            .doSomething()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(MyObject myObject) {

                }
            });
```

My question is:

**Is it possible that onNext is called more than once?
If yes, in which occasion?**

Comment: You may want to use `Single` instead of `Observable` in your MyApi interface. With `Single`, `onNext` is called at least once (or it's an error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, no it's impossible, of course if you do not emit more items in  `doSomething()` method.

But there is another, quite usual cases, for instance, if you use `Local first` approach and subscribing on `hot` observable which will emit new item each time when data in data base has change.

E.g. using retrofit:

```
@Override
public Observable<List<FollowMeUser>> getFollowMeUsers() {
    return realm.where(FollowMeUser.class)
            .findAll()
            .asObservable()
            .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded);
}

getFollowMeUsers()
.subscribe(users -> {Timber.d("saved data has changed")}, Timber::e);
```

Each time when you will insert/modify/delete `FollowMeUser` collection, all subscribers of `getFollowMeUsers` will be notified.

Answer (score 0):

If your retrofit returns an array/list of data, onNext is called multiple times.
But if your retrofit returns a single data objext, onNext will be called only once.
Example:

```
//POJO 
class User {
int userId;
String UserName;
}

//POJO 
class UserData {
List<User> users;
}

interface RetrofitGithub {
@GET("...")
Observable<List<User>> getUsers(); 

@GET("...")
Observable<UserData> getUserData(); 

}
```

If you subscribe to getUsers() onNext will be called multiple N times.(N = size of the list)

If you subscribe to getUserData() onNext will be called only once.